# Doctrine2 Caching of updated Elements

Tags: caching, doctrine-orm

I have a problem with doctrine. I like the caching, but if i update an Entity and flush, shouldn't doctrine2 be able to clear it's cache?
Otherwise the cache is of very little use to me since this project has a lot of interaction and i would literally always have to disable the cache for every query.
The users wouldn't see their interaction if the cache would always show them the old, cached version.

Is there a way arround it?

Comment: Do you just want to turn off the cache completely? I know you can clear the cache with $deleted = $cacheDriver->deleteAll();

Comment: @Gohn67: How do i get the CacheDriver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is according to the documentation on Doctrine2 on how to clear the cache. I'm not even sure this is what you want, but I guess it is something to try.

Doctrine2's cache driver has different levels of deleting cached entries.

You can delete by the direct id, using a regex, by suffix, by prefix and plain deleting all values in the cache

So to delete all you'd do:

```
$deleted = $cacheDriver->deleteAll();
```

And to delete by prefix, you'd do:

```
$deleted = $cacheDriver->deleteByPrefix('users_');
```

I'm not sure how Doctrine2 names their cache ids though, so you'd have to dig for that.

Information on deleting cache is found here: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/caching.html#deleting

To get the cache driver, you can do the following. It wasn't described in the docs, so I just traced through the code a little.

I'm assuming you have an entity manager instance in this example:

```
$config = $em->getConfiguration(); //Get an instance of the configuration
$queryCacheDriver = $config->getQueryCacheImpl(); //Gets Query Cache Driver
$metadataCacheDriver = $config->getMetadataCacheImpl(); //You probably don't need this one unless the schema changed
```

Alternatively, I guess you could save the cacheDriver instance in some kind of Registry class and retrieve it that way. But depends on your preference. Personally I try not to depend on Registries too much.

Another thing you can do is tell the query you're executing to not use the result cache. Again I don't think this is what you want, but just throwing it out there. Mainly it seems you might as well turn off the query cache altogether. That is unless it's only a few specific queries where you don't want to use the cache.

This example is from the docs: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/caching.html#result-cache

```
$query = $em->createQuery('select u from \Entities\User u');
$query->useResultCache(false); //Don't use query cache on this query
$results = $query->getResult();
```

Comment: I wonder, did they delete "deleteByPrefix()" on v.2.2.2? I made full search on doctrine source and these method cannot be found

Comment: `deleteByPrefix` is not available for memcache driver.

Answer (score 4):

Are you talking about saving and fetching a new Entity within the same runtime (request)? If so then you need to refresh the entity.

```
$entity = new Entity();
$em->persist($entity);
$em->flush();
$em->refresh($entity);
```

If the entity is managed and you make changes, these will be applied to Entity object but only persisted to your database when calling $em->flush().

If your cache is returning an old dataset for a fresh request (despite it being updated successfully in the DB) then it sounds like you've discovered a bug. Which you can file here >> http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/secure/Dashboard.jspa

Comment: I tried exactly that. I load the entity, make changes, persist it, flush it, refresh it. Still the same. But maybe that is because i refresh the entity and not all of its related objects so the related objects still come from the cache?

Comment: when you say "load" the entity, do you mean create it or fetch it from the DB? If its being fetched then its in a "managed" state and you don't need to use the persist() method on it. Also refreshing a managed Entity could remove any modifications you've made to it. If its new: create -> persist -> flush -> refresh. If its managed (fetched from the DB): fetch -> (make changes) -> flush.

Comment: I tried the same, refresh does not really help to "fight" cache.
It works like this:

$entity = $service->loadCached();
echo $entity->getData(); //returns data which is cached

$em->refresh();
echo $entity->getData(); //returns data which is NOT cached

Which sounds good, but in does not invalidate actual cache, so on next run of loadCached() you will still get old data.
Looks like there's no other way but clearing cache manually like Gohn67 suggested.

Answer (score 3):

Doctrine2 never has those delete methods such as deleteByPrefix, which was in Doctrine1 at some point  (3 years ago) and was removed because it caused more trouble.

The page http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/caching.html#deleting is outdated (The next version of the doctrine2 document will see those methods removed). The only thing you can do now is manually managing the cache: find the id and delete it manually after each update.

More advanced doctrine caching is WIP: https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/pull/580.

Comment: Yeah, old ticket, still I'm curious. I'm looking into "deleteByPrefix", but can't find anything about it. What kind of problems did it have? Performance issues? Maybe I should open a new question just about that.